# NetworkManager: Suppress Autconnect in special cases

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

My setup: I have a VPN connection (wireguard, managed by NetworkManager) that I like to keep on almost always, which is why it is set to autoconnect (connection.autoconnect = yes). I have a second VPN connection (openconnect) which I manually turn on sometimes.

Now I have the issue that whenever I turn on the openconnect VPN, the wireguard VPN is also turned on (even if I stopped it manually before), and the two VPNs clash and nothing works anymore, no DNS resolution, no connection at all.

Is there a way to configure a connection in NetworkManager (preferably using nmcli) such that it usually autoconnects, but "yields" to another connection? In other words, a configuration like "Usually autoconnect A, but if B is active, don't autoconnect A".

I know the exact opposite (connect A if B is active) is possible through connection.secondaries